# laravelログイン機能作成後、ログインユーザー登録をしようとするとエラーが発生して登録できない。

Tags: laravel

laravelのbreezeでログイン機能を作成しました。その後、別の学生新規登録画面を作成し、保存機能をつけました。その保存機能を試すために、ログインユーザー登録しようとすると下記エラーが発生します。解決方法なども色々と調べてみたのですが、分からずなので…お手数ですが、ご教授いただきたいです。

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, test@test, $2y$10$bIqaxvp.Za18Ntdk3h4hjuzh/PvZ9OKpVLIqV55KlmpqspapcnDVW, 2024-01-18 21:32:12, 2024-01-18 21:32:12))
```

Laravel 8
PHP 7.3

RegisteredUserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

2023_12_19_211715_create_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('user_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->string('user_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージのとおりですね。
DBのカラム名が user_name なのに対してモデルやコントローラでは name を使っています。

Comment: 早急に回答いただき助かります、ありがとうございます。
ご指摘のとおり、モデルやコントローラーのnameをuser_nameに変更したところ、該当のエラーは出なくなったのですが、ログインする際に、名前の箇所を入力しているにもかかわらず、名前は必須項目ですとの下記エラーが出てしまうのですが、どのような原因が考えられますでしょうか？
Whoops! Something went wrong.
The user name field is required.

Comment: 入力フォーム（bladeファイル）とコントローラでのVakidateとの食い違いがないか、再度確認して下さい。特に、標準でついてきたログイン画面を流用・加工している場合は、入力項目を電子メールからユーザ名に変更していると思いますので、修正漏れがないか十分にチェックして下さい。

Comment: 教えていただいたようにregister.blade.phpの該当箇所をuse_nameに変更したところ、エラー解決いたしました。検索しても解決できず、長い間悩んでいたので本当に助かりました、ありがとうございました！